# JSTL: Invalid syntax for function signature in TLD

Tags: jstl

I am trying to define a function in myTld.tld file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">

<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>customFunctions</short-name>
<uri>/WEB-INF/tags/myTld.tld</uri>

<function>
   <description>
       my Desc
   </description>
   <name>isActive</name>
   <function-class>com.Functions</function-class>
   <function-signature>boolean isActive()</function-signature>
 </function>
</taglib>
```

From El script i am calling like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="customFunctions" uri="/WEB-INF/tags/myTld.tld"%>
${customFunctions:isActive()}
```

Every time i do this, i am getting

```
Invalid syntax for function signature in TLD.  Tag Library: customFunctions, Function: isActive
```

Comment: Show us the corresponding Java method signature.

Comment: Please find it as public static boolean isActive()
 {
  final boolean isActive = false;
  return isActive;
 }

Comment: Shot in the dark: remove the extra space between `boolean` and `isActive` in the XML.

Comment: It is not there in actual code that i am running through eclipse, while pasting here it is added by mistake.

Comment: The tomcat is not giving me any further information as what is going wrong with the syntax other than the mentioned line.

Comment: You're **sure** it's a space and not a tab character in the real XML?

Comment: Hi Matt,It seems there was no issue. I almost tried till 2 hours for the same code and it did not work. I left it and then came back and it started working correctly without making any modification..:-)Thanks for your support.

Comment: Okay, you should probably just delete this question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<function-signature>boolean isActive()</function-signature>
```

to

```
<function-signature>java.lang.Boolean isActive()</function-signature>
```

Also change `<description>my Desc</description>` to one line. It could be (could be not) a problem as well.

Comment: Is this requirement specified somewhere? (One about using java.lang.Boolean instead of boolean).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issue with respect to function-signature. Description can be broken to multiple line as long as they are closed in the proper tag structure.
Even the return type can be given as primitive.

But thanks for your support. I just tried after few hour the same thing and it ran successfully.
Not sure why Tomcat gave me strange error(Even after multiple compilation and redeployment). Though i feel the Tomcat should be little more smart enough to tell the exact error when it says signature is wrong.The tomcat log also did not gave me any other information.